# Accessing localhost from AVD

Tags: android, drupal, localhost, android-virtual-device, acquia

I am up with Drupal development on a localhost environment. I want to view by website on the Android AVD. The URL of my website is `http://mywebsite:8082`
I tried accessing it using the URL `10.0.2.2:8082` but this does not take me to my website instead it takes me to the default website provided by `Acquia Dev Desktop`.

To add more, the server name given to the default website provided by `Acquia Dev Desktop` is `localhost` while the server name of my website is `mywebsite`

Comment: remove port number and then try...

Comment: Not working without the port number :(

Comment: What web server are your running, Apache,IIS ??

Comment: Try (http://10.0.2.2:8082/mywebsite) or (http://localhost/mywebsite) in a browser first to see if it works

Comment: Not working. The browser is stuck at the loading page.